# Web usb looses its pairing on browser restart

Tags: google-chrome, usb, webusb

I have an app that I developed and it uses webusb to print to a Hp Thermal printer. The app works ok and prints just fine. The issue is that whenever I restart the browser the pairing is lost and then I have to re-pair every morning before starting work. Is there some javascript or setting that I need to enable in chrome to have it remember the pairing once the browser/pc is restarted.

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior for USB devices which don't have a serial number, as the browser can't tell that the same device is plugged in when the computer restarts.

There is a workaround available for users who can set device policies, as the [WebUsbAllowDevicesForUrls](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#WebUsbAllowDevicesForUrls) policy allows you to pre-configure a set of USB device permissions for the sites you choose.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply followed the link and added the registry values not sure if i added them correctly, but it doesn't work. The registry value had to be condensed like so [{"devices": [{"product_id": 3689, "vendor_id": 1008}], "urls": ["https://webkiosk.mysite.com", "https://webkioskdev.mysite.com"]}] however it still asks me to pair the device everytime chrome is restarted. What did I miss

Comment: The urls need to start with https://.